# Getting exception while create Token using passport Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-5.8, laravel-passport

Everything is working fine till yesterday.
But Today while login through api I am getting an exception while creating token.
Exception is :
**Replicating claims as headers is deprecated and will removed from v4.0. Please manually set the header if you need it replicated.**

I don't know where things go wrong. If you have any solution it will really appreciate it, Thanks.

code for creating token : $user->createToken('fullaccess')->accessToken;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too faced the same issue, a quick solution will be to downgrade the package  lcobucci/jwt : 3.3 . It must have been upgraded to 3.4 during composer update which threw the deprecation warning.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same problem and temporarily have downgraded `lcobucci/jwt` package version from `3.4.0` to `3.3.3`.  My exception stacktrace is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65003024/laravel-passport-problem-replicating-claims-as-headers-is-deprecated-and-will)

Comment: Okay, Let me try this

Answer (score 1):

I'm deeply sorry for causing confusion or issues. Please check https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/issues/550#issuecomment-733557709 for my full explanation on why this approach was taken and why it isn't considered a BC-break in my PoV.